# Explanation to the flow of charge

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, lightning

I came across a really cool Cymatics video:

[image: Cymatics - Science vs Music]

There is one part in the video which is unclear to me. Please refer to the snapshot below taken at 05:15.

I see the equipment being close to a Van de Graaff, please correct me if I'm wrong. How is it possible that the person under the suit is not affected by the charge? Is it because the suit is metal, and charge flows to the ground through the suit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.**

The suit is of a conducting material and charge thus moves inside the suit material much more likely than through the content (the person) inside the suit.. This is called a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) and is an effective shielding mechanism from electric shocks. Excess charge will stay on the outer surface of a conducting object and charge will redistribute on the surface so to cancel each other out - thus no electric field is established inside the suit and no charge will move towards the interior.